# how to explain generics used in ImmutableList.builder().build() in guava?

Tags: java, guava

I just saw this kind of code  `ImmutableList<String> list= ImmutableList.<String>builder().build();`
which really confused me. How to understand the diamond after ImmutableList.?

Comment: That is the optional ‘TypeArguments’ in a [method invocation syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).  In this case, there isn’t much point to using a third party API for it, since [Collections.emptyList()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29) does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Most parameterized types in java show up on a type. This looks like so:

```
interface List<T> {
    void add(T elem);
}
```

So, any `List` type is parameterized, and as generics is really just a mechanism to link things, what it links is that a `List<String>` has an add method that takes `String` objects, and a `get(int)` method that returns a `String`, etc.

But, methods themselves may also want this linking behaviour. For example, let's say I want to make a method that takes 2 arguments of the same type, and returns the first non-null one. Here too I want to link things: The types of the 2 argument, and the return type? All the same thing, caller's choice as to what it might be.

Java supports this: Methods can ALSO have generics:

```
public <T> T firstNonNull(T a, T b) {
    return a == null ? b : a;
}
```

is valid java, and you can call it:

```
String a = firstNonNull("hello", "world!");
```

Compiles without requiring a cast.

Java will infer generics if it can; it does that in my previous example (the two arguments are both strings; java infers you meant T to be String there). But you can, if you want, be explicit about it. This is where this funky syntax comes in:

```
Number a = ClassContainingFNN.<Number>firstNonNull(null, null);
```

You need the dot to use this syntax, hence why I had to make the call a little longer. With the ImmutableList builder method, java can't (easily) infer what type you wanted, as the call to `builder()` itself doesn't let the compiler know that you're attempting to build a list of, say, strings. That's why forcing it by explicitly telling java what you want the type param to be is useful, thus, why the usual way to call this builder is:

```
ImmutableList.<String>builder().add(aString).add(anotherString).build();
```

Java will always try to infer *something* if you don't explicitly pick something, but it would just infer `Object` here. Unless you wanted a list of objects, you need the 'forcibly pick a type' option.

Answer (score 0):

See java support [jls-15.12](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L706) for supporting `TypeArguments` after entering `Type.`

> ```
> MethodInvocation:
> MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )
> TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
> ```

The [builder](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java#L706) is generic method

> ```
> public static <E> Builder<E> builder()
> ```

And because it's static you **entered before** method name the type using diamond operator

In case of new instance it'll be as you expected:

> ```
> new ImmutableList.Builder<Color>()
> ```